# Determining path of a relative URL without filename

Tags: c#, uri

I use this simple code to retrieve the absolute path from the links I parse from a web page.
`CurrentAddress` is the webpage address, `testingAddress` is the link I found

```
String uri = new Uri(new Uri(currentAddress), new Uri(testingAddress)).AbsoluteUri;
```

This works pretty much always and it can discern whether or not the `testingAddress` is relative to the page or not.

I'm getting a problem with relative links that do not specify a filename, for example `"/portal/combo/?v=1"`

In that case the exception

> "the format of the URI could not be determined"

gets raised.

If I specify the `testingAddress` is relative it works, but at that point I lose the functionality of the code that was meant to be able to understand how to combine paths on its own and I have to check the paths manually before joining them.

Is there a way to make this work or I have to suck it up and add controls to preparse the `testingAddress` string?

Comment: The sample of the value that raises an error is in the question: `"/portal/combo/?v=1"`. `Uri.TryCreate` would bypass the error, but that's not my concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the overload that takes in `string?` as the second parameter (from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Uri__ctor_System_Uri_System_String_)):

> ## Uri(Uri, String)
>
> Initializes a new instance of the Uri class based on the specified base URI and relative URI string.
>
> ```
> public Uri (Uri baseUri, string? relativeUri);
> ```

### Example

```
var currentAddress = "https://stackoverflow.com";
var testingAddress = "/questions/67382787/determining-path-of-a-relative-url-without-filename";
String uri = new Uri(
    baseUri: new Uri(currentAddress), 
    relativeUri: testingAddress).AbsoluteUri;

// uri is "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67382787/determining-path-of-a-relative-url-without-filename"
```

Comment: This seems to work perfectly. The whole thing is resolved simply by not parsing testingAddress as an URI but leaving it as a string. I never would have guessed it.